# issue when trying to display youtube search results with different heights

Tags: angular, css, youtube, youtube-api, flexbox

I am busy with a basic youtube-player app using angular4.x.  I am using a instant search component using rxjs which makes a request when a input field changes after 400ms of not changing...

I initially  tried to display the search results in a col-md-4 div in order to have three results per line.  I then had an issue where some of the thumbnails or text of some search results had different heights and then would wrap to the next line...

I then applied flexbox styling to the search results and it seems to be better however some of the thumbnails are always missing and I only have two search results per line now where there's definitely space for 3-4.

Any idea how I can go about getting this to work/why some of the video thumbnails doesn't show (even though they were returned by the youtube API)?

**my search result template:**

```
<div class="eqrow">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="play(result.id, result.title)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="sr-only">
                    Play</span>
            </button>    
            <div class="caption">
                <h6>{{result.title}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**my eqrow style:**

```
.eqrow {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.eqrow > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**my search component:**

```
import {  Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';    
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromEvent';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';

import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
import { SearchResult } from '../../models/search-result.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-box',
  template: `
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" [formControl]="term">
  `
})
export class SearchBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  term = new FormControl(); 
  @Output() loading: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
  @Output() results: EventEmitter<SearchResult[]> = new EventEmitter<SearchResult[]>();

  constructor(private restService: RestService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.term.valueChanges.debounceTime(400)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .do(() => this.loading.emit(true))         // enable loading
        .switchMap(term => this.restService.search(term))
        .subscribe(
        (results: SearchResult[]) => {
            this.loading.emit(false);
            this.results.emit(results);
        },
        (err) => { 
          console.log(err);
          this.loading.emit(false);
        },
        () => { 
          this.loading.emit(false);
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `"col-md-4"` coming from Bootstrap? ... if so, which version? ... also, most likely the `"col-md-4"` class will interfere with the flex properties, so I recommend to remove one or the other.

Comment: @LGSon I fixed that tag(it wasn't present in my actual code only on stackOverflow)...  Yes it's bootstrap 3.x

Comment: Then try to change them to a custom name and use those as flex classes. To combine Bootstrap 3.x with Flexbox might not be such a good idea. Another option could be to use Boostrap 4, which is based on Flexbox

Comment: When I remove the col-md-4 from bootstrap the gap between the two coluns disapear however it's still only two columns where i'd prefer three smaller thumbnails per row.  And still some of the thumbnails are missing...

Comment: If you can provide a working code sample showing exactly that, I will be able to suggest a solution. ... if not a stack snippet, a fiddle or a codepen would be fine

Comment: A code sample of what?  Do you need to see more than the above?

Comment: Which exact Bootstrap 3.x version do you use? ... give me the link

Comment: "bootstrap": "3.3.7",

Comment: Posted an answer. Let me know if it is useful and I will add some explanation how it works

Comment: Since I got no response I deleted my answer.

Comment: @LGSon I did comment on your answer.  That's strange wonder what happened can you please add it again?  Sorry about that and thanks again for all your effort.

Comment: I have undeleted the answer. You did comment, and then I added a comment, which were the one I meant you didn't respond to, and since you didn't, and I had an answer which I felt were incomplete, I deleted it. So if you could reply on my last comment, we could have the answer updated and accepted, and also say more than _Would this be a start_, which I'm not so happy with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the `col-md-4` class, which is a Bootstrap class that might interfere with the Flexbox properties, with `my-col`.

Together with the added `justify-content: space-between` (to `eqrow`)  and `flex-basis: 30%` in `my-col`, we create a *gutter* between the items, and they will per row have equal height by default, since the `align-items`/`àlign-content` defaults to `stretch`.

Then by also make i.e. the flex items `my-col` flex containers (nested Flexbox's), one can further control its children using Flexbox properties, which again can be both flex items and flex containers.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z5sdfr9e/)

```css
.eqrow {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.eqrow .my-col {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="eqrow">
    <div class="my-col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="play(result.id, result.title)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="sr-only">
                    Play</span>
            </button>    
            <div class="caption">
                <h6>{{result.title}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="play(result.id, result.title)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="sr-only">
                    Play</span>
            </button>    
            <div class="caption">
                <h6>{{result.title}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="play(result.id, result.title)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="sr-only">
                    Play</span>
            </button>    
            <div class="caption">
                <h6>{{result.title}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="play(result.id, result.title)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="sr-only">
                    Play</span>
            </button>    
            <div class="caption">
                <h6>{{result.title}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="play(result.id, result.title)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="sr-only">
                    Play</span>
            </button>    
            <div class="caption">
                <h6>{{result.title}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-col">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{result.thumbnailUrl}}">
            <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="play(result.id, result.title)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="sr-only">
                    Play</span>
            </button>    
            <div class="caption">
                <h6>{{result.title}}</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your effort.  That works for the most part however videos whith different heights are still a problem as the alignment is still off...  Also there's still thumbnails missing however I think that could be related to the instant search function...  Any idea how I can go about handling videos with different thumbnail heights?

Comment: @user2094257 If you can provide a real search result, so I can see what you see, I might be able to detect what went wrong

Comment: @LGSonSorry I must have missed your comment.  What do you mean by a real search result?  e.g. when I search for "music" I get a list of results back however i've noticed that sometimes e.g. the first thumbnail is missing but if I repeat the search it shows up.

Comment: @user2094257 Which then should mean that the suggested solution I gave actually work, right?, besides a thumbnail is missing once in a while ... and if that is the case, and as the missing thumbnail has nothing to do with my solution, I would appreciate if you also accept the answer, and I will update it with a little bit more info on what I did.

Comment: @user2094257 Thank you. I'm at work now and will update the answer as soon as I get back. If you have any further questions, just drop me a note here and I'll do my best to assist you.